# Do fields and particles have a one-to-one correspondence?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, field-theory, wave-particle-duality

Do fields and particles have a one-to-one correspondence? That is can we have two different particle from same field (excitation) or can one unique particle gets created by different field (excitation)?

Comment: Your question title “doubt in QFT” could use a revision, I think. You’d have to provide alternative explanations to a wide range of experimentally confirmed QFT predictions to justify “doubting” it.

Comment: The equivalence between field and particle descriptions isn’t a postulate, but a mathematical peculiarity of the equations of QFT. Without studying those equations it’s impossible to explain this equivalence without resorting to inaccurate and confusing analogies.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov Do you mean that energy eigenstates of fields *just happen to* behave as experimentally observed particles? I think the equivalence of particles and fields is a discovery.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really about what we call what, isn't it?

What we call a particle is a certain grouping of the states of the quantum fields. How we do such a grouping? Usually we do it because different states are related to each other by some symmetry. For example you can transform states with different momentum and polarizations into each other using shifts, rotations, Lorentz transformations and discrete symmetries, such as $\mathcal{CPT}$.

The same way we introduce the multi component fields. You can always consider the components as separate fields, however it is often useful to group them into a multi component field to reflect the symmetries of the model.

This works not only for the spacetime symmetries but also for the internal ones. E.g. you rarely would encounter someone calling quarks of the same flavour but with different colors different particles because of the color gauge symmetry.

On the other hand if the symmetry is broken but is present in a more fundamental theory you may still feel compelled to call the states not related by the conserved symmetries as particles with different properties. The external electric field breaks the rotational symmetry but you usually don't call electrons moving with different transverse momenta different particles.

This works also the other way. In the Standard model it is useful to combine the left neutrino and left electron fields into a single doublet and consider the right electron a completely unrelated field as this reflects the fundamental electroweak symmetry. But we live in the vacuum where this symmetry is broken by the Higgs field and our usual electron involve the simultaneous excitations of the lower component of the doublet and of the right electron field. Usually the neutrino and electron are distinguished even in the regimes when you really could treat them as different faces of the same particle.  And left and right electrons are called this way even when they become completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

The terms "particles" and "fields" are often used interchangeably in high energy physics. However, every fermion field has both particles and anti-particles. Other than that the identity of a particle is directly associated with a specific field.

Particles and fields carry different degrees of freedom. They have spatiotemporal degrees of freedom and also internal degrees of freedom, such as spin, color etc. However, these degrees of freedom are not considered as being associated with different kinds of particles and fields, because their states generally exist as superpositions of different degrees of freedom.

Comment: So mass spin and charge is unique for a given field ?

Comment: See the edited answer